# why is selenium webdriver not finding my element

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

https://www.mykplan.com/participantsecure_net/TermsAndConditions.aspx
I am doing find by id/xpath/name and they all fail for the accept button. Here is my latest effort

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="Accept"]').click()
```

copied straight from chrome web tool

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The button is located inside a frame. Given xpath is correct only inside a frame. I tested xpaths in chrome console and this is what I got:

In case of main page (https://www.mykplan.com/participantsecure_net/TermsAndConditions.aspx) xpath couldn't be located:

```
$x('//*[@id="Accept"]');
[]
```

In case of frame contents only (https://www.mykplan.com/participantsecure_net/TermsAndConditionsBottom.aspx) xpath could be found:

```
$x('//*[@id="Accept"]');
[<input type=​"submit" name=​"Accept" value=​"I agree" id=​"Accept">​]
```

In selenium, I guess you need to switch to a frame before looking for xpath. I think that web driver function

```
driver.switch_to_frame("frameName")
```

should help. In your case, frame with buttons is called "bottomFrame".

Comment: hmm so I did what you said but it didn't work, I didn't get an error during switch frame, but I still get a failed to locate element for the accept button

Comment: Does it work if you open web driver for frame subpage (.../TermsAndConditionsBottom.aspx) and without switch_to_frame? If yes then switching to a frame fails.

Comment: sorry I misread your answer, you were right this whole time, I changed the main page I open to bottom, and took out the switch to frame and it worked! :)

Comment: ok one last question, now that I am logged in, I want to check my balance. I noticed its inside a "MAINFRAME", but when i do switch_to_frame('MAINFRAME') it says unable to locate..... <frame src="MykPlanPart.aspx" name="MAINFRAME" scrolling="AUTO" noresize="" marginheight="10" marginwidth="10" border="0" frameborder="0" framespacing="0">

Comment: ah I answered my own question, I suspected that the page was not finishing loading but wasn't sure how to wait, it was driver.implicitly_wait(5)

Comment: You can also create a loop which checks if some element is present. It is safer than constant interval.